# Sequence git pull-commit-push at once in JetBrains products

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to be able to do the git pull-commit-push action in 1 shortcut (clicking 1 option) in Android Studio / IntelliJ.

It would be such a convenient solution. Can I do it?

Comment: What is stopping you from trying it out?

Comment: I was trying to look for it in Android Studio and was googling for the answer without a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dmitriy said, you can force update on push rejection, see screenshot.

Now, the fastest keyboard shortcut I can think of, assuming you have predefined commit messages in .gitmessages and unchecked all the "Before commit" safety checks, is : ctrl+k for commit, shift+tab twice to put the cursor on commit button, press enter to commit, then ctrl+shift+k for push, the combination shift+tab once, press enter. That's 7 keystrokes.

So you can record this : go to Edit / Macros / Start macro recording / type the keystrokes / go back to Edit / Macros / Stop recording.

Then go to Preferences / Keymap / Macros / right click on your recorded macro and select Add Keyboard shortcut and voila your convenient shortcut.

If you are alone with your code and are fine with a cluttered git history and meaningless commit messages, it answers your question.

[image: in preferences]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has Commit+Push action, and also could automatically pull if the push is rejected. It is not exactly the same, but quite close.